# Как в строке заменить \\n на \n?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, считанная извне. В этой строке текст и нет переходов на новую строку. Вместо них там содержатся `\n` написанные "от руки", которые обозначают эти переходы.

Так вот, смотрю на строку под отладчиком, вижу, что на самом деле все `\n` дополняются до `\\n`.

Начинаю проводить замену:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(textToPrint, "\\n", "\n");
```

Но это не помогает, ничего не происходит. Как быть? Что делаю не так?

Comment: скорее всего надо менять на `\r\n`, а еще лучше использовать [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: в php делается вот так... $str = 'some\nsome\nsome';
$str = str_replace('\n','\\\n', $str);

Comment: А String.replace в .NET отсутствует?

Comment: "\r\n" - не работает.  "string.replace" не могу использовать (отсутствует .Net). "Regex.Replace(textToPrint, "\\\n", "\n")"  тоже не прошло

Comment: Может, `Regex.Replace(textToPrint, @"\\n", "\n")`? А вдруг в тексте есть ``\n``, которые вовсе не обозначают LF?

Comment: @Alerr как это у вас отсутствует .NET, если тег c#?!

Comment: string output = Regex.Replace(textToPrint, @"\r\n?|\n", \n);

Comment: `Regex.Replace(textToPrint, "\\\\n", "\n")` -- это regex, слеши нужно экранировать как бэ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы смотрите на то, что показывает отладчик, с пониманием. Он показывает, как выглядела бы исходная строка на C#, а не реальные символы, которые там внутри. А реально в тексте там везде по два символа `\` и `n`, никаких двойных бекслешей там нет.

Делайте просто:

```
// @"..." отключает интерпретацию `\` как escape character, так что в тексте будут именно
// два символа \ и n, как и у вас
string s = @"Как хороши, как свежи были розы\nДостаточно и половины дозы!";
// @"\n", как и раньше - строка из двух символов.
// "\n" - "обыкновенная" строка, в ней компилятор заменит \n на символ перевода строки
// с кодом 0x0A
string decoded = s.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
// печатаем для проверки, видим разрыв строки
Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/J981fP

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew прав, и `@"\n"` не сработает. Нужно именно `@"\\n"`. Буквально только что проверил в VS.

Comment: @n01d: Это противоречит описанию ТС и пробному коду. Попробуйте сами оттрассировать код, который я привёл, и убедитесь.

Comment: да, ошибся. `Regex.Replace` и метод `String.Replace` работают по-разному. `Regex.Replace` правильно найдёт в вашей строке именно по `@"\\n"`.

Comment: @n01d: ЕМНИП, ``\`` в `Regex.Replace` интерпретируется повторно, да.

Answer (score 3):

> под отладчиком, вижу, что на самом деле все `\n` дополняются до `\\n`.

Это означает, что в тексте вместо перевода строки есть обратные косые черты с буквой `n` после них.

Чтобы регулярное выражение нашло такие сочетания символов, необходимо использовать

```
@"\\n"
```

Тут `\\` обозначает 2 буквальных символа `\`, т.е. шаблон для нахождения символа обратной косой черты.

[Демо](http://ideone.com/p150Eq):

```
var textToPrint = @"Текст 1\nТекст2";
Console.WriteLine(textToPrint);         // => Текст 1\nТекст2
var output = Regex.Replace(textToPrint, @"\\n", "\n");
Console.WriteLine(output);
// => Текст 1
//Текст2
```

Comment: эм, `@` как раз позволяет использова спец символы без экранирования и не нужно экранировать `\\`` Дополнительно, То есть: `@"\n" == "\\n"`

Comment: @Grundy: смысл в том, что в тексте присутствуют символы ``\``. Надо найти подстроки из 2-х символов: ``\`` + `n` - > `@"\\n"`. Можно попробовать и `Regex.Unescape(textToPrint)`, но это может и не сработать.

Comment: @n01d, На самом деле нет: слова _под отладчиком, вижу_ намекают что в строке присутствует символ `\ ` - который под отладчиком как раз и показывается как `\\ ` поэтому при использовании `@` искать надо точно `@"\n"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, вот тут и ошибка `\ ` + `n` - > `@"\n"` или `"\\n"`

Comment: [`"\\n"` найдёт символ LF](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cn&i=%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%0d%0a%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82).

Comment: Короче, я просто объяснил, почему не работает регулярка в вопросе и  как можно решить задачу с помощью регулярногоо выражения. Простой `string.Replace`, конечно, будет эффективнее. Только если задача усложнится и нужно будет учесть контекст, нужен будет `Regex`.